# assign a variable along with iterating for loop with items of another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have two arrays and each one contain 14 items and a main for loop (I want `i` in this loop to do some behaviors).

I want to assign `pass` variable along with iterating `i` in the `for loop` with items of `values` array.

Here is what I mean:

```
var values = [1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3];
var indexs = [3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18];
var pass = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) { 
    // when i is equel to each item in "indexs" array assign "pass" with "values" item
    // for example if i == 3  ===>  pass = values[0] or 1
    // if i == 5  ===>  pass = values[1] or 3
    // if i == 18  ===>  pass = values[14] or 3
}
```

Comment: for (var i = 0; i < 14; i++) {  // i will never = 18 as 18 is > 14. I don't understand what you're trying to do in this question, what does it mean that pass should have either of two values? It can only have one value.

Comment: You need to clarify better what you are trying to do.

Comment: `pass = values[indexs.indexOf(i)]` will get the first match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want to check whether your `indexs` array contains index `i` of `for` variable. If so, try to use `includes` function:

```
const values = [1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3];
const indexs = [3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18];
let pass = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < 14; i++) { 
    if (indexs.includes(i)) {
      let arrayIndex = indexs.indexOf(i);
      pass = indexs[arrayIndex];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for understanding me with my poor English:) Thats it: `pass = values [arrayIndex];`

Comment: @SaraRee I am glad to help you!:)